# How do I use outsourced and editable scripts in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am currently developing a website with Nuxt. A certain `javascript` file should be editable after building to change the content of a table. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Up to now I tried to include the `javascript` file as plugin without success. Furthermore, I also failed the attempt to swap the script as follows:

```
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
  <div>This is a Text!</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-outsourced-script.js"></script>
```

Currently my Code looks like this:

**Bootstrap-Vue** table:

```
<b-table
        borderless
        striped
        hover
        responsive
        :sticky-header="stickyHeader"
        :items="folderPermissions"
        :fields="folderGroups"
      >
</b-table>
```

Content to be swapped out:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stickyHeader: true,
      keyword: '',
      sortBy: 'xxx',
      sortDesc: false,
      folderGroups: [
        {
          key: 'drive',
          stickyColumn: true,
          label: ' ',
          isRowHeader: true
        },
        ...
      ],
      folderPermissions: [
        {
          drive: 'Some Text',
          id: 0,
          a: 1
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My wish would be to have `folderGroups` and `folderPermissions` in the code shown above in an outsourced `javascript` file to easily modify them and see the changes on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you do, or if you try to import your js file with your data like `import { folderGroups, folderPermissions} from './my-outsourced-script.js`, you cannot change the file without rebuild your nuxt app.

Try to build with your file as below:

```
{
"folderGroups": [
    your datas
  ],
"folderPermissions": [
    your datas
  ]
}
```

And dynamic import in your component:

```html
data() {
  folderGroups: [],
  folderPermissions: []
},
mounted() {
  this.$http.get('/js/my-outsourced-script.json').then((response) => { // no need `assets`
    console.log(response.body)
    this.folderGroups = response.body.folderGroups
    this.folderPermissions = response.body.folderPermissions
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error.statusText)
  })
}
```

Comment: I think I'm acting a little stupid. So currently I've inserted your code like this:

export in my component: [Pastebin to my component](https://pastebin.com/raw/VvE3rCLf)

my-outsourced-script.js: [Pastebin to my js file](https://pastebin.com/raw/Zi7kMXVv)

When I now run nuxt generate, I get a SyntaxError in my outsourced js file due to the ":"

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast. I refactored the code, and use json instead.

Comment: All right, thanks! Unfortunately the content is still not shown to me. The following error appears in the console: `TypeError: "this.$http is undefined"` Could this be because I am running `npx nuxt generate`?

Comment: `$http` is an alias of `$axios`, you can use `$axios` instead. Do you use axios? Or you can use directly fetch. Replace `this.$http.get` by `fetch`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I took fetch now and generated the whole thing. However, the following error always occurs in the console of the browser: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/xxx/json/my-outsourced-json.json. (Reason: CORS request not http).` Do I have to change anything to get it to work locally?

Comment: Solved it: added in `nuxt.config.js` - `{ src: './json/folderTableContents.js' }` to head and converted json content to const (js). In `mounted()`I've only added these two lines: `this.folderGroups = JSONDATA.folderGroups` `this.folderPermissions = JSONDATA.folderPermissions`. (JSONDATA is the name of const in old json file)